How to easily detect new appended data with bpy?
Fellow bpy coders, do any of you know an easy method/trick to detect newly added appended datablock in the user scene?
context:
I intend to automatically detect new appended objects in user scene in order to ensure that no name or idx collision happens within the context of my plugin custom properties. Therefore i should catch the list of appended objects as soon as it is possible in order to potentially change the .name and .uuid values of my objects
Cheers

if we could look at user undo history stack, & if last undo step was an append operation, we could act accordingly. but the undo stack is written in C unfortunately

Generally use bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post
For attribute: bpy.msgbus
Since blend data update will trigger redraw, It can also be like this:
# Detect whether bpy.data.objects item has been added or deleted
import bpy

def draw():
    new_len = len(bpy.data.objects)
    if draw.old_len < new_len:
        print("New Object appended")
    elif draw.old_len > new_len:
        print("Some Object deleted")
    draw.old_len = new_len

draw.old_len = len(bpy.data.objects)
bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')


Hi
Wouldn't this function also detect dupplicated objects?

Yes, if you run bpy.context.object.copy(), you will see it print: New Object appended. But it doesn't know if this is a copy operation.

It also fails if you append an object and delete another object in the same iteration. (I assume the object was added by code) Something like https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.session_uid might help ?

This is because the drawing code is not triggered immediately in the same iteration. For this situation, you need another approach.
